# What is the probability that 1 woman and 2 men are chosen if the following is given?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a classroom, there are 8 women and 5 men. A committee of 3 people is to be formed for a project. What is the probability that 1 woman and 2 men are chosen?

For this problem, the directions say for me to use permutation or combination.

I used combination as order doesn't matter.

So $$ P(1W \cap 2M) = \frac{(8C1)(5C2)}{13C3} $$
but the answer I got was wrong so I think I did the whole process wrong except the denominator. How would I solve this?

Comment: what you have written here is correct.

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: It looks right to me. 1 of 8 women without replacement, 2 of 5 men without replacement, over the sample size of 3 from 13 without replacement.

Comment: Your formula is correct. You might have computed it wrongly, else something in either the Q or A is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered (it's currently on the first page of unanswered probability questions):

As remarked in several comments, your result is correct.